# EF Core: Many to Many relationship without navigational entity collections

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

I want to implement a model abiding by the principles of DDD & aggregates.

I have a many-to-many relationship between a `Company` & `User`, but these are both aggregate roots, and I want to model their relationship by referencing Ids not the entity types i.e.

```
public class Company
{
    public List<int> UserIds { get; set; }
}

public class Users
{
    public List<int> CompanyIds { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to use the Fluent model builder API to allow this? i.e. so that it would build a many-to-many table consisting of the columns: `| UserId | CompanyId |`

Comment: EF model is **data model**, which generally is different from *domain model*. Since EF won't follow your DDD principles, either create separate models or break your principles. [EF Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) clearly states *"Many to many relationships **require** a collection navigation property **on both sides**"*

Comment: That quoted sentence seems to be true only if you wish to stick to the standard EF conventions. I should be able to achieve what I'm after using David's answer and the: [Indirect Mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#indirect-many-to-many-relationships) documentation.

Comment: It still has navigation properties and special link "entity", so I don't see how this fits to your DDD principles. For sure it doesn't serve `List<int>` type properties, and is just another (explicit) way of representing many-to-many **data model** relations.

Comment: EF core now allows you to Fluently map against private fields, so I should be able to make those navigational properties private and fluently configure them, then provide a public `IEnumberable<int>` that just selects the list of UserIds. You are right though in that really I should create a separate data model, I'm just trying to avoid extra complexity for this particular project whilst trying to set some aggregate boundaries; a middle ground I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you'd just be opting-out of the convenient and useful EF Many-to-many pattern, which has a hidden linking table, and adding a first-class linking entity.  eg

```
public class Company
{
    public List<CompanyUser> CompanyUsers { get; set; }
}

public class Users
{
    public List<CompanyUser> CompanyUsers { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyUser
{
    public int CompanyId {get;set;}
    public int UserId {get;set;}
}
```

And configure CompanyUser to have its key on (CompanyId,UserId) and an alternate key (or unique constraint) on (UserId, CompanyId).

It's obviously more convenient to put `CompanyUser.Company` and `CompanyUser.User` Navigation Properties on the linking entity, but entirely optional.